# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{z-n} - \frac{1}{n}\right) $ define a meromorphic function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{z-n} - \frac{1}{n} \right)$$
defines a meromorphic function.

What I've done so far is:

Let $R > 0$ and choose $N$ so that $N > 2R$.  Write the original series as $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{2n-z}{(z-n)(n)} + \sum_{n=N + 1}^{\infty} \frac{2n - z}{(z-n)n}.$$

The first term shows that we have poles at the natural numbers less than N.  I was trying to show that the second part defines a holomorphic function for $|z| < R$.  To do this I was going to use Montel's theorem, so I was also going to use the W-M Test.  To that end I was trying to get a bound on $\frac{|2n-z|}{|(z-n)(n)|}$ by something that I knew converges. However, I keep getting bounds that seem harmonic.

I was wondering if this is the right way to approach the problem, and if anyone could offer any hints for finding the bound.

Answer (score 2):

The sum diverges, because for large $n$ the summand is approximately $-2/n$.
Perhaps you mean $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{1}{z-n} + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: okay, so I'm correct in thinking it diverges then, thank you. I double checked the problem and it definitely is - and not + do you have any ideas of how else to do the problem?

Comment: What's the source of the problem?  It's probably a misprint.

Comment: it is an old qualifying exam problem I found posted online, so there's no way for me to find out if it is a misprint.  I will try to do it with the other function to make sure I understand what is happening.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Maybe I'm wrong, but I rather find that, as $n \to \infty$: $$ \frac{1}{z-n}+\frac{1}{n}=-\frac{z}{n^2}+\mathcal{O}(1/n^3)$$ Thus the series is convergent.

Comment: That's true if $z$ is not a positive integer.

Comment: @Guest This wouldn't be  the first time a qualifying exam problem had a misprint.  If it's not possible to ask a question of the examiner, the recommended procedure is to point out the error and, if possible, answer what you **think** was the intended question.  Being able to see what the question should be might be a better indication of graduate-level mathematical ability than being able to answer a correct question.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Hello, could you explain why
$${1\over z-n}+{1\over n} = -{z\over n^2}+O(1/n^3)$$

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case the sum is actually intended to be $$\tag 1\sum_{\nu \geqslant 1}\frac{1}{z-\nu}+\frac 1\nu$$

Consider the product $$\prod_{\nu\geqslant 1}\left(1-\frac z\nu\right)e^{z/\nu}$$

By the classical results concerning Weiertrass factorization this converges normally on $\Bbb C$ and has roots precisely at $z=1,2,\ldots$, and its logarithmic derivative is precisely $(1)$, hence $(1)$ converges normally over $\Bbb C-\{1,2,\ldots\}$ and is meromorphic there with simple poles at each singularity.

Comment: You don't want to include $\nu = 0$.  You don't need Weierstrass factorization: quite elementary estimates prove this converges almost uniformly on $\mathbb C \backslash \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ with simple poles at each singularity.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I didn't say you have to *use* Weiertrass' factorization (in fact that is quite useless here), just results related to it, for example that such products converge under appropriate conditions, and what happens with logarithmic derivatives $\sum f_\nu'/f_\nu$ of normally convergent products $\prod f_\nu$ of holomorphic functions.